# Sign in to google and keep session with python

Tags: python, authentication

Currently I have a project that uses python requests (or any other requesting library besides selenium) to google login to a 3rd party website.
I tried a lot of ways to login but with no success such as:

- I log in google into the browser and copy the entire session to requests and then log in to the 3rd website, it doesn't work or dynamic, even when I go to google's homepage, it still can't log in.
- I have tried something like oauth2 but it only helps to get the user's information and not to log in to something else in the 3rd party.
  Is there anyone who can help me?

Comment: Why can you not use selenium?

Comment: It is very heavy, currently I need to use about more than 1000 req in 1 time. I tried selenium but upto 70 80 selenium can work fine on my VPS (8GB ram, 8vCPU, 150GB SSD)

Comment: Hi, please provide a minimal reproducible example of your problem so the community can help better. [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.